# selecting a df row by month formatted with (lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I'm having some issues with geopandas and pandas datetime objects; I kept getting the error

```
pandas Invalid field type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'>
```

when I try to save it using gpd.to_file() apparently this is a known issue between pandas and geopandas date types so I used

```
df.DATE = df.DATE.apply(lambda x: datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z'))
```

to get a datetime object I could manipulate without getting the aforementioned error when I save the results. Due to that change, my selection by month

```
months = [4]
for month in months:
    df = df[[(pd.DatetimeIndex(df.DATE).month == month)]]
```

no longer works, throwing a value error.

```
ValueError: Item wrong length 1 instead of 108700.
```

I tried dropping the pd.DatetimeIndex but this throws a dataframe series error

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'
```

and

```
df = df[(df.DATE.month == month)]
```

gives me the same error.
I know it converted over to a datetime object because print(df.dtype) shows DATE datetime64[ns, UTC] and

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row.DATE.month)
```

prints the month as a integer to the terminal.

Without going back to pd.Datetime how can I fix my select statement for the month?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `df.DATE` returns a Series object. That doesn't have a `.month` attribute. The dates inside the Series do, which is why `row.DATE.month` works. Try something like:

```
filter = [x.month == month for x in df.DATE]
df_filtered = df[filter]
```

Before that, I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with `pd.DatetimeIndex(df.DATE).month == month)` but a similar fix should take care of it.

Comment: When I was using pd.datetime to convert my date strings to datetime objects df = df[pd.Datetimeindex(df.DATE).month == month] to get all the points in that month. Or at least some code similar to that, I changed it a lot trying to get it to work with the new datetime object I created using lambda and I don't recall what it was exactly when I started getting the pandas Invalid field type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> error.